# How do I get raw gnss data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android-gnss

I am developing a web app for indoor navigation system .For this I tried the geolocation api to get gps.It doesn't give latitude and longitude as accurate as I would like (even with highaccuracy enabled).I learnt that by using gnss we can get accuracy of a few cm. I verified this using an app and it's true.
I know we can get gps,accelerometer etc data using javascript. Is there someway to get gnss data purely by using javascript/html?